Vercel Serverless Functions Size Exceeds 250 MB - How to Optimize NPM Packages
I'm working on a small puzzle app that uses Python as the backend and a React frontend with NextJS.
While I'm trying to deploy on Vercel, I fail with the error of "Serverless Function has exceeded the unzipped maximum size of 250 GB"
I have optimized my Python imports to ensure they take the smallest size. But when I investigate my npm installs, I see super large packages:
size    count module
------ -----  ----------
129.47mb 1 ✓  @next/swc-win32-x64-msvc
81.98mb  1 ✓  next
81.36mb  1 ✓  react-icons
37.39mb  1 ✓  typescript
6.38mb   1 ✓  date-fns
5.63mb   1 ✓  @chakra-ui/anatomy

I would assume I need next for sure. I can try to get rid of react-icons and find an alternative, but would it be possible to get rid of the @next/swc-win32-x64-msvc when deploying on Vercel?
Alternatively is there a minified version of Next available somewhere?
Would appreciate the help! Thanks!
